# R packages/libraries equivalent to Fabrication/Factory-Bot?

Tags: r, testthat

I note the [`testthat`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/testthat/versions/2.0.0) package indicates it has been influenced by the Cucumber, RSpec, etc Ruby libraries.

In that (Ruby) spirit: Are there R packages/libraries that provide the functionality of [Fabrication](https://www.fabricationgem.org/) or [Factory-Bot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot).

I take the point about fixtures/factories hiding coupling and complexity when used in unit tests.

Given that caveat, what approach (packages) do people use in R when writing tests that are more integration than unit tests?